# Getting an exception while creating simple Spring AOP Throws Advice Demo

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven, spring-mvc

hi I am getting Exception as ****thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException****
while try to make a simple Spring AOP throws advice Demo. 
Please some one help me out.

The detail code with exception is mentioned below

MyInterface.java

```
package com.Spring.Aop.SpringAOPThrowsAdvice;

public class MyImplClass implements MyInterface {
     public void m1(){

            int java4s = 10/0;
            System.out.println("Am in business method..");

        }
}
```

MyInterface.java

```
package com.Spring.Aop.SpringAOPThrowsAdvice;

public interface MyInterface {
       void m1();
}
```

MyThrowsAdvice.java

```
package com.Spring.Aop.SpringAOPThrowsAdvice;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import org.springframework.aop.ThrowsAdvice;

public class MyThrowsAdvice implements ThrowsAdvice {

    //First preference
    public void afterThrowing(ArithmeticException e)
    {
        System.out.println("This is from ArithmeticException method");
    }

    //Second preference
    public void afterThrowing(Method m, Object args[], Object target,Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Am from 4 parameters method called from "+m.getName());
    }

    //Third preference
    public void afterThrowing(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Fom single parameter method");
    }

}
```

OurLogic.java

```
package com.Spring.Aop.SpringAOPThrowsAdvice;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

public class OurLogic {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Resource res = new ClassPathResource("spconfig.xml");
        BeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory(res);

        MyInterface inter =(MyInterface)factory.getBean("id3");
        inter.m1();
    }
}
```

spconfig.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans>
 <bean id="id1" class="com.Spring.Aop.SpringAOPThrowsAdvice.MyImplClass" />
 <bean id="id2" class="com.Spring.Aop.SpringAOPThrowsAdvice.MyThrowsAdvice" />
 <bean id="id3" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">

      <property name="proxyInterfaces" value="com.Spring.Aop.SpringAOPThrowsAdvice.MyInterface" />
      <property name="interceptorNames" >
                  <list>
                       <value>id2</value>
                   </list>
       </property>
       <property name="target">
               <ref bean="id1"/>       
       </property>     

 </bean>

</beans>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.Spring.Aop</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringAOPThrowsAdvice</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>SpringAOPThrowsAdvice</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aop -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Exception is:

```
May 11, 2017 12:47:38 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spconfig.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 2 in XML document from class path resource [spconfig.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 8; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:404)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:342)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory.<init>(XmlBeanFactory.java:73)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory.<init>(XmlBeanFactory.java:61)
    at com.Spring.Aop.SpringAOPThrowsAdvice.OurLogic.main(OurLogic.java:12)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 8; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:396)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:284)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1900)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:740)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:374)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:613)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3132)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:852)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:841)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:770)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)
    ... 5 more
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply haven't put the namespace bean in your config file header : http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/xml.html

Comment: adding to what @Matthieu has already mentioned, specify this:   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<!-- <bean/> definitions here -->

</beans>`

Comment: @coolgirl  actually that was my mistake I for got to put namespace bean in my config file that's what the exception suggested. but put namespac here in my question Matthieu is right.